# Interfaces in UML class diagrams - should realizations also show interface operations?

Tags: architecture, uml

I've been doing a lot of work with UML class diagrams lately, and I'm trying to get clarification on a question.

Let's say I declare an interface on my class diagram - let's call it `ISomething`.  On the interface, I declare an operation called `doSomething()`.  I then proceed to create a new class that realizes the interface, called `SomethingImpl`.

Now, the question that I'm trying to answer is this - should the `SomethingImpl` class on the diagram also show the `doSomething()` operation, or can it be left out because its existence is implied?

I've tried to find answers online, but with no luck.  The diagrams that I've seen are very inconsistent in this regard - some of the show interface operations on realizations and some don't.  As long as my diagrams make sense and clearly express intent, I'm not too concerned about being 100% correct.  However, I am curious about this particular scenario.

Answer (score 2):

It depends, like always.

What you show on a diagram is intended for a certain audience. Now, if that audience is already enlightened and knows the context you can leave out details. If not you are better served showing them. Anyhow, what I do generally is to create overview diagrams with less details and then add various detail diagrams. Depending on your UML tool (I use Enterprise Architect) it is possible to connect elements with a diagram the opens when it's double clicked. This diagram is then element-centered with detail information.

Comment: Thanks Thomas - I agree that in practice, it depends on your audience.  And tooling, like EA, makes it much easier to get down to the details.  However, in this case my question is specifically around constitutes 'correct' UML in my example - more academic than anything else really.

Comment: Tooling makes it easier. But without you can create a "book" with diagrams and references that work analogously. UML itself leaves diagrams an open space and the diagram structure is explicitly said to be not restrictive but open to what transports the message.

Answer (score 1):

The class you create might implement only a part of the interface's operations, e.g. in Java could be an abstract class or even a concrete class if the not implemented operations have a `default` implementation (Java 8 or newer). So, for at least these situations you might want to list the actual implemented operations.